# Updating a ListBox on another window from sql server table, c# wpf

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, listbox

start of by saying im using c# in wpf, so I am having this new problem with a listbox in my main window (SalesScreen). I have a window called SearchScreen that has a datagrid that is populated from a table on a sql server. Now my goal is to be able to select a row from this datagrid and click a button that says "Add to Cart". When this button is clicked it will successfully sends the selected row to the new table that is populating a Listbox on the main window. Keep in mind both windows stay open at the same time. So the problem I am having is that the ListBox does not update automatically when the tblCart changes on the server. Any advice on how this could be done?  Once again I'm still in a beginners stage on c#.

This is my xaml that starts the ListBox(just a basic ListBox):

```
<ListBox Height="261" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="43,69,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="240"/>
```

This is a method that is used for a textbox changed on the SalesScreen (The main window). When the textbox changed event takes place the row is added to the server and the ListBox is properly updated in the window. I tried to call this event with the "Add to Cart" button click but it had no change. Now if I use the "Add to Cart" button on the SearchScreen and then come back to the main window and do the textboxchanged event, it will update both items added.

```
public void addtoList()
    {
        cn.Open();
        String cmdString = "Select Title, Price from tblCart";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdString, cn);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        double subT = 0;
        double tax = 1.09;
        double total = 0;
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            int count = dr.FieldCount - 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {

                listBox1.Items.Add(dr["Title"].ToString() + dr["Price"].ToString());
                subT += Convert.ToDouble(dr["Price"]);

            }

        }
        total = subT * tax;
        subTotal.Text = subT.ToString();
        totalBlk.Text = total.ToString();
        cn.Close();
    }
```

This is the addtoCart button:

```
private void addBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SalesScreen ss = new SalesScreen();

        DataRowView drView = (DataRowView)dGrid.SelectedItem;
        String s = Convert.ToString(drView.Row["ID"]);
        String cmdString = "INSERT INTO tblCart(Title, GenreID, Price, Year, UML, Quantity) Select Title, GenreID, Price, Year, UML, Quantity FROM tblMovies WHERE ID = " + s;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdString, cn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        ss.addtoList();
    }
```

So basically, I can update it from the same window using the textchanged event, but when it comes to sending it from one window to another I have been most unsuccessful with this challenge. Any advice would be more than greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your button click event there is no open connection when your command is executed.

Comment: The connection is already open at that point, I did try it though to make sure, but just told me the connection was never closed.

Comment: You shouldn't have open connections, only when they are required. Each connection should be opened and disposed of as soon as its finished. You can do that either with a Using Statement, where the connection is encapsulated and closed automatically, or, you should be using a Try/Catch statement to catch any exceptions. In the finally statement, you close the connection.

Answer (score 0):

modify your click button event

```
   private void addBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SalesScreen ss = new SalesScreen();

    DataRowView drView = (DataRowView)dGrid.SelectedItem;
    String s = Convert.ToString(drView.Row["ID"]);
    String cmdString = "INSERT INTO tblCart(Title, GenreID, Price, Year, UML, Quantity)  Select Title, GenreID, Price, Year, UML, Quantity FROM tblMovies WHERE ID = " + s;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdString, cn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cn.Close();
    ss.addtoList();
}
```

Comment: So, I just closed all the connections so I could do it like this, with cn.Open and cn.Close before and after the ExecuteNonQuery, but still nothing.  The listbox remains to not update on the SalesScreen window when i exit the SearchScreen window.  This has been my life for the past few days ;).  Thank you for the time to respond as well.

Comment: So here is what I did to solve this problem. I had the SalesScreen close when the button was clicked to go to the SearchScreen.  When I hit the back button on the SearchScreen to go back to the SalesScreen, I put the addtoList() method in the same method as the InitializeComponent(); and it works great.  A sort of refresh.

Answer (score 0):

```
public SalesScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        addtoList();

    }
```